# Clustered node computers

Tags: 12.04, server

I'm new to Ubuntu and currently running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

I have seen many questions regarding clustering computers, and i was wondering if i can use the node computers as standalone computers or are they only "raw computing power"?
Meaning: Is it only the server computer i can use with a screen?

Just wanted to know before i jump into the challenge.

Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got your question correctly but as i see you mean that if you can use the node computers as a normal computer

yes, if you are making a Cluster Computer using a normal computers over LAN
then yes, you can use them

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what type of clustering you use.

If you use a [single system image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-system_image) solution (for instance [Kerrighed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerrighed)), or a distributed operating system, all cluster nodes together will look like one single computer to users.

However it is not necessary to use SSI for distributed computing. If your programs are written accordingly, several computers can work together on the same problem using [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). Often MPI is  combined with a scheduling tool (for instance [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System)) to launch the MPI-aware application on several nodes in a controlled manner. In such a configuration each node is still an individual computer and can (in principle) be used independently of the rest.

Edit: I just found a [setup guide for an mpich cluster with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster).